# How to get an Extract of a DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have got an *.svg file that I am traversing iterativly within this function

```
function traverseSVG( root ){
    var stack = [root];
    var c;
    var item = new Item( "root" );
    item.parent = item;

    while( stack.length > 0 ){
        c = stack[ stack.length - 1 ];
        if( c.nodeType == 1 && c.childNodes.length > 0 ){
            stack.push( c.firstChild );
        } else if( c.nextSibling != null ){
            stack.pop();
            stack.push( c.nextSibling );
        } else {
            while( stack.length > 0 ){
                c = stack.pop();
                if( c.nextSibling != null ){
                    stack.push( c.nextSibling );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within the item variable i like to store some elements that meet a certain criteria. The item variable has the following constructor:

```
function Item( e ) {
    this.e = e;
    this.children = [];
    this.parent = null;
}
Item.prototype.addChild = function( c ){
    this.children.push( c );
    c.setParent( this );
    return c;
}
Item.prototype.setParent = function( p ){
    this.parent = p;
    return p;
}
```

For example, if the input svg looks like this: [sample svg](http://pastebin.com/Dh93gNBp), than the Item should store all group and path elements, with attention to the hierarchical order. So in the new tree the defs Element should not be included, but the group inside the defs element should become a direct child of the defs parent. This like an Extract of the input DOM.

Consider that there also an test function that returns true or false if a element of the input should be included in the new DOM. My question is: How can i include this in the traversal function, best? The problem is to keep track of the right current item, when the traversal goes deeper in the DOM and comes that up again. I have tried a lot but no solution did the trick.

Thanks for help in advance!

Greetings philipp

Answer (score 0):

So, after some time of brain twisting I made it work. Just for everybody who might come to the task of implement some similar, here is my solution:

```
function traverseSVG( root ){
    var stack = [root];
    var c, i;
    var item = new Item( root );
        item.parent = item;

    while( stack.length > 0 ){
        i = null;
        c = stack[ stack.length - 1 ];

        if( Item.isItem( c ) && item.canAppend ){
            i = new Item( c );
            item.addChild( i );
        }


        if( c.nodeType == 1 && c.childNodes.length > 0 ){
            stack.push( c.firstChild );

            if( i != null ){
                item = i;
            }

        } else if( c.nextSibling != null ){
            stack.pop();
            stack.push( c.nextSibling );

        } else {
            while( stack.length > 0 ){
            c = stack.pop();

            if( c === item.e ){
                item = item.parent;
            }

                if( c.nextSibling != null ){
                stack.push( c.nextSibling );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Using the i variable for new Items did the trick. Greetings...